# Calling the original function after tweaking arguments is an incorrect use of the R-API?

Tags: r, r-extension

I am trying to create a small extension for R here for embedding the current time on the R prompt: https://github.com/musically-ut/extPrompt

Things seem to be working overall, but `R CMD check .` raised a warning:

> File '[truncated]..Rcheck/extPrompt/libs/extPrompt.so’:
>    Found non-API call to R: ‘ptr_R_ReadConsole’
>
> Compiled code should not call non-API entry points in R.

The concerned file is this: https://github.com/musically-ut/extPrompt/blob/master/src/extPrompt.c and occurs on line 38, I think.

```c
void extPrompt() {
    // Initialize the plugin by replacing the R_ReadConsole function

    old_R_ReadConsole = ptr_R_ReadConsole;
    ptr_R_ReadConsole = extPrompt_ReadConsole;

    // ...
}

int extPrompt_ReadConsole(const char *old_prompt, unsigned char *buf, int len,
         int addtohistory) {

    // ...

    // Call the old function with the `new_prompt`
    return (*old_R_ReadConsole)(new_prompt, buf, len, addtohistory);
}
```

I am trying to make the `R_ReadConsole` API call. However, since a different plugin (like mine) could have overridden it already, I do not want to directly invoke `R_ReadConsole` but the function which previously was at `ptr_R_ReadConsole`.

Is this an incorrect use of the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [r-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-October/069922.html):

> As for incorrectly using the API - yes. Since R CMD check is telling
>   you this is a   problem, it is officially a problem. This is of no
>   consequence if the package works for you and any   users of it, and
>   the package is not to be hosted on CRAN. However, using this symbol in
>   your code may not    work on all platforms, and is not guaranteed to
>   work in the future (but probably will!).